# Symfony Assert DateTime JMSSerializer

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have endpoint postOrder - create entity order. In entity order I have fields with type DateTime and I want when somebody write string instead DateTime I have "Not valid, should be DateTime" . For other fields I use like this

```
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
```

or

```
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *           pattern= "/^[\d() \-+]+$/",
 *           message= "This text cannot contain numbers"
 * )
```

or

```
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
```

I get all request then serialize then deserialize for concrete entity when validate and have information from assert in endpoint, but for DateTime this not work
I use FosRestBundle and JMSSerializer this is my action

```
 /**
 * Post Order.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 * resource = true,
 * description = "Post Order",
 *  parameters={
 *      {"name"="comment", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="comment"},
 *      {"name"="interview_date", "dataType"="date", "required"=false, "description"="date conect for developer"},
 *      {"name"="contact_date", "dataType"="date", "required"=false, "description"="date contact fir TIM"}
 *
 *  },
 * statusCodes = {
 *      200 = "Returned when successful",
 *      400 = "Returned secret token is not valid"
 * },
 * section="Order"
 * )
 *
 * @RestView()
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return View
 *
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException when not exist
 */
public function postOrderAction(Request $request)
{
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($data, 'json');
        $serviceLead = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($data, 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeServiceLead', 'json');
        $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($serviceLead);
            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                $view = $this->view($errors, 400);

                return $this->handleView($view);
            }
```

and fields

```
class Orders
{


    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"get_all_orders_admin", "get_all_orders", "for_vip"})
 */
protected $comment;

    /**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="interview_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"get_all_orders_admin", "get_all_orders", "for_vip"})
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $interview_date;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="contact_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"get_all_orders_admin", "get_all_orders", "for_vip"})
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $contact_date;
```

Now I have error when I try deserialize for entity order

```
{
"error": {
"code": 500,
"message": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": [
  {
    "message": "Invalid datetime \"some_string\", expected format Y-m-d\\TH:i:sO.",
    "class": "JMS\\Serializer\\Exception\\RuntimeException",
```

How to return correct error or assert, without 500, in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `deserialize()`, that is already checking your entity for validity against your Doctrine annotations since the JMS Serializer [already integrates with the Doctrine ORM](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer).

If deserializing fails, an [exception is thrown](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/Handler/DateHandler.php#L96), which is what you are seeing.

All you need to do in your case is put your code in a `try/catch` block if you want to handle that yourself:

```
public function postOrderAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($data, 'json');

    try {
        $serviceLead = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize(
            $data,
            'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeServiceLead',
            'json'
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $view = $this->view((array) $e->getMessage(), 400);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

I didn't see your `view()` function but I assumed it was expecting an array of strings of error messages so I cast exception message to an array.  Either way you get the idea.

Comment: I have * @RestView(). Thnks,  I have information error. Thnks

Comment: I got very similar situation, but I use the param convert to get the entity, which means I can't use the try catch solution. is there a way to do it like that?

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific situation is but I imagine you could write a custom param converter